# How to solve $\cos(\frac{\alpha }{2} )=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2} } }$ for $\cos(\alpha)$ using half-angle formula.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have $\cos(\frac{\alpha }{2} )=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}  } }  $

How can I get $\cos(\alpha ) $ from this?

I know this identitiy.

$\cos(\frac{\alpha }{2} )=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\alpha )  }{2} }  $

But just cant figure out, how to do it.

Comment: What values are known? If $a,b$ are known solve $\sqrt{ \frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ for $\cos(\alpha)$.

Comment: Remember that you have the standard identities $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1 = 1-2\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, along with $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. You should be able to use these to determine everything you care about.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

You have $$\cos(\alpha/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Just square both sides and solve for $\cos(\alpha)$

Comment: Thank you. But how could I do that with sinus(alpha/2).. because there is again only cos(alpha).. so I can solve it only for cos(alpha)?

Comment: Ana, Help me to understand.   All we need to do is find an expression for $\cos(\alpha)$.  By squaring both sides, multiplying by $2$, and subtracting $1$, we have it.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(\frac{\alpha }{2} )=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}  } }  $

$\cos^2(\frac{\alpha }{2} )=\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}$

$\frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(\alpha))=\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}$

$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{2a^2}{a^2+b^2} - 1$

---

half-angle formula

$\cos^2(\frac{\alpha }{2} ) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(\alpha))$

Comment: how could I do that if I have sinus(alpha/2) and i need to get sinus(alpha)? Identities are giving me only cosinus

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic I'd recommend you to ask that in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If we have that $a,b$ are given then we can use the above answers to say that

$$\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Then

> $$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{2a^2}{a^2+b^2}-1$$

If instad you have $\sin(\alpha/2) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ you can use that $\sin(\alpha/2) = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(\alpha/2)} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and you solve again for $\cos(\alpha)$.

If you want to exchange $\cos(\alpha)$ for $\sin(\alpha)$ it is always possible using $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$ and the identities that came from that. I think that in the comments was that what you pointed out.

$\cos^2(2\alpha) = \cos^2(\alpha)-\sin^2(\alpha) = 2\cos^2(\alpha)-1$

$\sin^2(2\alpha) = 4\sin^2(\alpha)\cos^2(\alpha)=4\sin^2(\alpha)(1 - \sin^2(\alpha))$

So what possibly be other interpretation of your question is that given

$$\cos(\alpha/2) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

what is $\sin(\alpha)$? We know that, because of this we have that

$$\cos(\alpha/2) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

So that $\cos^2+\sin^2 = 1$ and then we can use that

> $$\sin(\alpha) = 2\cos(\alpha/2)\sin(\alpha/2) = \frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}$$

And the answers quoted respect the fundamental equation of trigonometry.